# SSRS Calendar Report Displaying Day Numbers Inaccurately

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a SSRS report that displays employee vacation in a calendar format. I created my query and it returns the sample data shown here.

[image: CalendarData]

I created a matrix that has row groups Month and column groups Month and DayOfWeek.

[image: CalendarMatrix]

When I run the report with the calendar blank (no employees), it displays as expected.

[image: Calendar_NoEmployees]

I then inserted a table to add the list of employees who have vacation on the given date. When I run the report, the employee names are on the correct day, but the beginning and end of month boxes that were previously blank are now showing values in the DayNumber field.

[image: Calendar_Employees]

Can any one advise what I've done incorrectly?